# How to create a page which gets real time updates from PubSubHubbub

Tags: javascript, rss, real-time, publish-subscribe

I want to know if it is possible to use javascript/html or php, etc... to create a page that receives continuous updates from a feed that uses [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub)?

How can I do this?
I am new to this, and any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Random suggestion - booth [WebHooks](http://www.webhooks.org/) and [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) look cool.  [Article](http://blogmaverick.com/2009/08/25/the-internet-is-about-to-change/):

> Webhooks let applications talk to each
>   other using very simple HTTP. Webhook
>   enabled applications run (so far) on
>   app hosting sites in the cloud.  What
>   makes them different is that they
>   constantly scan  for POSTS to a
>   designated URL.   To use the
>   application, you register your
>   application with the other webhook
>   enabled application and provide  a
>   callback URL.  You POST   data from
>   your app to the url of the receiving
>   app, and monitor the callback URL for
>   its response. Your app then takes the
>   POST it received and processes it.
>
> Pubsubhubbub (PSHB) is a realtime,
>   multicasting webhooks enabled  publish
>   and subscribe system.  Historically on
>   the net, most information is received
>   after it is pulled.  For example, we
>   set up receive intervals for our
>   email. Our browsers update our RSS
>   feeds at pre determined intervals. We
>   repeat the same searches over and
>   over, just looking to see if there is
>   anything new. Even when we get alerts
>   for new email or information, the
>   alerts are generated by actively
>   polling the source. PSHB changes that.